# Error from popen() prints in shell, but not through a web-server

Tags: c

Issue : When `test.cgi` is run in `shell`, this is the output :

```
Content-Type: text/html

ls: /test_3/: No such file or directory
test
```

However when it is run through a web-server, this is the output :

```
test
```

Mission : To make it print the `ls: /test_3/: No such file or directory` through the web-server as well.

Compile and `chmod` : ( Tested. can run `reboot` as `root` through a web server. )

```
gcc test.c -o test.cgi && chmod u=rwx,go=xr,+s test.cgi
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

fputs("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", stdout);

setuid (0);

    FILE *pipe; 
    char buffer[100];

    pipe = popen("ls /test_3/","r");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe) != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s<br>", buffer);

    pclose(pipe);

fputs("test", stdout);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I expect it's forbidden in a webserver because of security reasons.

Comment: @user743414, it prints the "`test`" properly through the web-server. It can run `root` commands thanks to `setuid (0);` and `chmod u=rwx,go=xr,+s test.cgi`, I have also tested it with the `reboot` command through the web-server and it worked. To print the error in the question.. I tried adding `printf("%s",stderr);` to it.. but it did not work.

Comment: you want to redirect the output to stderr to stdout?

Comment: @Chris Turner, your comment was  very useful in doing research and finding the answer. I ended up adding  "`2>&1`" after the `ls /test_3/` and it worked. If your comment was posted as an answer, I would have probably selected it as the "chosen answer".

Comment: guys please put it as an answer, to avoid wasting time of people who come to this question, to read it and the comments and figure out it's already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error string is printed to stderr, you need to redirect it to stdout since that is what your web server is sending back to the browser.

Redirect stderr to stdout in your program, like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "To stderr\n");
dup2(1, 2);  
fprintf(stderr, "To stdout\n");
```

Or simply:

```
popen("ls /test_3/ 2>&1","r");
```